# visual studio "find" equivalent to grep -C10

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm used to doing this in my unix environment to see source code in context:

`$ find . | xargs grep -i -n -C10 "some function or term"`

And this helps me see the **context** of the string for which I am searching.

In Visual Studio, I can do Find and search for terms in source code, but not with any context... is this possible?

So while a typical Find Result looks like this:

```
D:\Path\To\File\SomeFile.cs(215): someFunctionIWannaSee(@Model.Foo.Bar());
```

I'm hoping to see something more like this:

```
                                  {some code above what I want to find}
                                  {some code above what I want to find}
                                  {some code above what I want to find}
                                  {some code above what I want to find}
D:\Path\To\File\SomeFile.cs(215): someFunctionIWannaSee(@Model.Foo.Bar());
                                  {some code below what I want to find}
                                  {some code below what I want to find}
                                  {some code below what I want to find}
                                  {some code below what I want to find}
```

Comment: What kind of context are you looking for? `FindAll` will show the file path, line number, and line of code containing the search term in the `Find Results` window.

Comment: @RufusL I want all that, plus a few lines before and after. I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: If you click a line in the search result window, it'll show you the file preview. I don't think it is possible with standard VS to get what you ask (nor I think this is always practical)